# Load Balancer GCP and Wordpress, i can't see the js and css

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

i configured a Load Balancer with a Mig (i had to migrate a static wordpress website to a scaling one), all works fine connecting to the load balancer IP over port 80, but when i try to connect with 443 some js and css can't be visible, i can just see text and not much more.

How can i solve this problem?
Thanks guys.

Comment: 1) Use the Chrome debugger and look for errors. 2) Go to Cloud Logging and look for errors. 3) Look for errors in the Apache and PHP logs.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley thanks for your quick reply 1) This is the error that is repeated several times **Mixed Content: The page at <URL> was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet <URL>. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS** 2) There are no errors over Cloud Logging just few warnings 3)server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name this version of mod_ssl was compiled against a newer library (OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019, version currently loaded is OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018) may result in undefined or erroneous behavior

Comment: When you put a load balancer in front of WordPress, you need to modify `wp-config.php` to process the HTTP header `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` to detect the protocol that the user is using and not the protocol the load balancer is using to connect to your backend. Google search for examples using `WordPress` and `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO`.

Comment: Still having issues with css and visualization of the page, is it possible that the problem is the configuration of the image i used to create the managed instance group? Because i can see the website without any issue connecting directly from the VM in the instance group but when i try to connect with Load Balancer  it create problems, so my question is, is it possible that the ssl configuration inside the VM create some conflicts with che certificates in load balancer? ps: the website is still using DNS over another IP waiting the migration also this could be the problem?

Comment: No - the issue is that you are serving mixed content. Google search and learn what the error message that you posted in your comment means. `Mixed Content: The page at <URL> was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet <URL>. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS `

Comment: No, I solved that problem, now the problem is about CORS policy, but i'm solving it

Comment: If you solved the question, post an answer. Otherwise, delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by inserting **at the top of the wp-config.php** file this code.

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
{
       $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
}
if ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) )
{
        $ips = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);

        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = trim($ips[0]);
}
elseif ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']) )
{
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'];
} elseif ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) )
{
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}
```